# How can I split a bunch of m4a files in chunks and replace their metadata with ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, batch-processing

I read through a lot of threads that adressed my issue partially and tried to write a script that splits an .m4a audiofile in parts and replaces its metadata.

I didn't manage to achieve this in a single line (Maybe you can tell me how to) but came pretty close with these two scripts. (I split them in two just for readability and debugging.)

```
#!/bin/bash
# cutaudio.sh

input=$1
output=$2
duration=$3

ffmpeg -i $input -map 0 -f segment -segment_time $duration -c copy "$output-%03d.m4a"
```

The above script works fine and splits the files in chunks of the provided length.

```
#! /bin/bash
# stripmetadata.sh


input=$1

n="1"
for i in $input*; do 
    title="Part $n"
    ffmpeg -i $i -map 0 -metadata title="$title" -c copy -y "$i"
    n=$((n + 1))
done
```

This script actually manages to replace the title in the metadata, however the files are also being stripped to the first second. They're all 33,7 kb in size after the second script. I am still new to ffmpeg so help would be appreciated a lot!

**Edit:**
Here's the resulting script, for anyone interested:
https://github.com/adrifromhh/cutaudio
I use it to cut downloaded Audiobooks (from youtube or recorded from Audible) in usable parts.

Comment: I mean, in your second script, you're attempting to write output data to input file (in the line where you call ffmpeg). This is the reason why your files end up getting stripped to 34KiB.

Comment: FFmpeg cann't edit files in-place. Upgrade to release 4.1 or newer. This now blocked, with a warning.

Comment: Thanks, your information helped!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on oguzismail's comment, you should write to a temporary file and then overwrite the original chunk file afterwards, e.g.,

`for i in $input*; do 
    title="Part $n"
    ffmpeg -i $i -map 0 -metadata title="$title" -c copy -y /tmp/tmp.m4a
    mv -f /tmp/tmp.m4a "$i"
    n=$((n + 1))
done`